# Filtering GeoJSON by properties time value

Tags: javascript, geojson, mapbox-gl-js

I have a GeoJSON with weather data from about 140 weather stations. The problem is that each station is listed 3 times, because the GeoJSON contains data from 3 different readings for each station: 3 hour ago reading, 2 hour ago reading and 1 hour ago reading. 
The url where I get this GeoJson from, lists data with the following sequence:  `-3h` data for all stations, then `-2h` data for all stations, and finally `-1h`data. This sequence is shown in the picture, and as you can see, the same station is listed 3 times (features #0, #142 and #283) according to the hour of the readings. It can also be seen that `properties time` format is `2020-02-22T21:00:00`, where minuts and seconds are always `00:00` for the `-3h`, `-2h` and `-1h` because readings are done at the hour.

[image: GeoJSON with same station listed 3 times]

When I run the script, it just shows me data from `-3h`, probably because it is the first date it gets in the sequence.

Here is the main part of the script, where I get temperature:

```
<script>
//Get current date-time withh same format GeoJSON uses 
var curdt = new Date().toJSON().substring(0,19); 

map.on('load', function() {
map.addSource('points', {
'type': 'geojson',
'data': 
'https://api.ipma.pt/open-data/observation/meteorology/stations/obs-surface.geojson',
 });
 map.addLayer({
 'id': 'Temp (ºC)',
 'type': 'symbol',
 'source': 'points',

  // filter data by properties time
  "filter": [
  "<=",
  [ "get", "time" ], curdt
  ],

 'layout': {
 "visibility": "none",
 'text-field': ['get', 'temperatura'],
 'text-font': ['Open Sans Semibold', 'Arial Unicode MS Bold'],
 'text-offset': [0, 0],
 'text-anchor': 'top',
 "text-size": 15
 });

  ---
 </script>
```

I would like to filter (ignore) older data and just get the `-1h` weather data. For instance, if `current date-time` is `2020-02-22T23:18:35` I would like to get the GeoJSON data for all stations having `properties->time: 2020-02-22T22:00:00`.

I have a very little knowledge of JS and I have tried to adapt one filter option and it works for `time <= current time` but how can I make it work for `time = (current time - 1h)`?

Is there any way to filter just the `-1h` data of the GeoJSON and display those values, instead of the `-3h` values that it is displaying now? Thanks.

Comment: Can you include one record of the actual GeoJSON data? The answer will depend what format the time data is actually included in.

Comment: @Steve Bennett Thanks for your reply. I have edited my comment with more details of the GeoJSON, but meanwhile I managed a way to solve the problem. Don't know if it is the "cleanest" way, but it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by filtering `propreties time` to show only `-1h`data instead of `-3h`data

```
 <script>
 //subtract one hour from current time
 var subtracthour = new Date();
 subtracthour.setHours(subtracthour.getHours()-1);
 // Can also subtrat extra minuts if needed
 //subtracthour.setMinutes(subtracthour.getMinutes()-15);

 // Convert to ISO Format used in this GeoJSON (2020-02-28T15:31:25)
 var dt = new Date(subtracthour).toJSON().substring(0,19); 

 // Apply the filter to get only "-1h" data 
 map.addLayer({
 'id': 'Temp (ºC)',
 'type': 'symbol',
 'source': 'points',

 'filter': [
 '>=',
 [ 'get', 'time' ], dt
 ],

 'layout': {
 'visibility": 'none',
 'text-field': ['get', 'temperatura'],
 'text-font': ['Open Sans Semibold', 'Arial Unicode MS Bold'],
 'text-offset': [0, 0],
 'text-anchor': 'top',
 'text-size': 15
 },

 ----
 </script>
```